# Производительность работы с sqlite при постоянном переподлючении к ней (python)

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlite3

Модифицирую чужую программу на python. В ней вызывается функция, которая читает тот или иной файл с диска и возвращает его значение. В моем варианте пишу альтернативную функцию, в которой все лежит в БД sqlite. Получается что-то вроде:

```
def get_tile (x, y, z):
  conn = sqlite3.connect(path + 'tiles.db')
  c = conn.cursor()
  c.execute("SELECT ...")
  ... # получаем данные
  conn.close()

  return data
```

Насколько критично для быстродействия постоянное подключение и отлючение к БД? Или лучше глобально в самом начале конектится к БД и в вызываемой функции использовать открытое подключение? (просто это с точки зрения архитектуры коряво будет, тк пишу что-то вроде доп модуля, без изменения основной логики приложения)

Comment: Зависит от того, насколько часто будет вызываться это взаимодействие с бд.

Comment: А в питоне есть переменные, живущие между вызовами функции ? глобальные например (хотя это плохой тон) или еще какие то, в области видимости только функции, но сохраняющиеся (мне кажется должны быть). Если есть, то на входе, если переменная пуста - коннект

Comment: @MichaelPak часто, чтение из БД и отдача по сети посредством веб-сервера web.py это основной функционал программы.

Answer (score 5):

Каждое подключение к БД занимает время. Постоянно висящее соединение отъедает память. Но время незначительно и используемая память тоже. Если запросы к БД идут постоянно, то оверхед на постоянные подключения/отключения может быть значительным. Поэтому общая рекомендация такая: если обращения к БД идут постоянно, то лучше её открыть один раз в начале работы программы и закрыть в конце. Если обращения редки, то можно подключаться/отключаться.

Но у `SQLite` есть своя специфика. Движок очень лёгковесный и работает обычно не с сетью, а с локальными файлами. Поэтому для `SQLite` можно в любом случае просто открыть БД и не закрывать пока программа работает.